# Prism ConfirmNavigationRequest() called twice when DataContext = this

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm using Prism and my views implement `IConfirmNavigationRequest` in order to enable them to perform validations and cancel the navigation if required.

My problem is that I have several views which don't use MVVM, and define `DataContext = this`. Doing so causes Prism to call my view's `ConfirmNavigationRequest()` twice, which means I ask for the user's response twice.

Basically what's going on is this:

1. Prism checks if the view implements `IConfirmNavigationRequest` and calls `ConfirmNavigationRequest()` on it if it does.
2. The user is asked whether he'd like to continue.
3. The user clicks OK and `ConfirmNavigationRequest()` returns `true`.
4. Prism checks if the viewmodel (in my case, it's the view again) implements `IConfirmNavigationRequest` and calls `ConfirmNavigationRequest()` on it if it does.
5. The user is asked again whether he'd like to continue.

As you can see, Prism asks my view for confirmation **twice** because it queries both the view and the viewmodel.

So my question is, how can I prevent this from happening or how can I detect which call is which so I can ignore one of them? I thought about investigating the `continuationCallback` parameter, but I don't like this solution so much since it's not unlikely it'll break in the next versions of Prism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I got so far is the one I got from DCherubini at [Prism's forum](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/347486), which suggests that I won't set the view's `DataContext` on my `UserControl`, but use an inner element that will hold the view, and set the `DataContext` for it instead:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

grid.DataContext = this;
```

instead of

```
<UserControl x:Name="uc">
</UserControl>

uc.DataContext = this;
```

This should work, but it means I need to change each view individually. A solution that doesn't require making changes to the views would be nicer.